# Clio 2 1.2 1998 strange sound from brakes

Tags: brakes, brake-rotor, brake-pad

When I'm applying a brake there is coming strange sound from left front wheel. My guess was that it's coming from brakes, so I disassemble the wheel. Below is a picture of breaking pads and rotor from this wheel. There is strange texture on rotors.

I would like to ask if It's necessary to change both, pads and rotors, or can I change just pads, based on picture. In simple words, is rotor still usable?

[image]

Comment: Best advice, change both, pads and rotors

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My first strong suggestion that you need a stand to go with the jack - apologies if it is hidden behind the hub assembly.

You need to fit two new rotors with new pads on both sides for the front.

If you don't, the braking performance will be out of balance and could cause you to loose control.